# Oracle REF can't go through

Tags: sql, oracle

My tables :

```
create or replace type t_exemplaire as object  
( IdExemplaire     Number(10),  
  NumeroRayon      Number(5),  
  Document     ref t_document )
```

/

```
create table exemplaire of t_exemplaire(   
    primary key(IdExemplaire),  
    constraint Document_c CHECK ( Document is not null))
```

/

```
create or replace type t_emprunt as object  
( IdEmprunt         Number(10),  
  DateD             DATE,    
  DateF             DATE,  
  Emprunteur_ref    ref t_emprunteur,  
  Exemplaire_ref    ref t_exemplaire )
```

/

```
create table emprunt of t_emprunt(  
    primary key(IdEmprunt),  
    Emprunteur_ref scope is emprunteur,  
    Exemplaire_ref scope is exemplaire,  
    DateD default sysdate)
```

/

I would like access to my attribute type like that :

```
Exemplaire_ref.IdExemplaire
```

but I obtain numerous errors.

How can I use REF to access attributes ?

DEREF do not work , I use oracle XE 11

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the table an alias and then refer to the column by:

```
<table_alias>.<ref_column>.<object_field>
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/213ef9/4)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
create or replace type t_document as object  
( IdDocument     Number(10) )  
/

create table document of t_document(   
    primary key(IdDocument)) 
/

INSERT INTO document 
          SELECT t_document( 1 ) FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT t_document( 2 ) FROM DUAL
/

create or replace type t_emprunteur as object  
( IdEmprunteur     Number(10) )  
/

create table emprunteur of t_emprunteur(   
    primary key(IdEmprunteur)) 
/

INSERT INTO emprunteur 
          SELECT t_emprunteur( 1 ) FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT t_emprunteur( 2 ) FROM DUAL
/

create or replace type t_exemplaire as object  
( IdExemplaire     Number(10),  
  NumeroRayon      Number(5),  
  Document         ref t_document )  
/

create table exemplaire of t_exemplaire(   
    primary key(IdExemplaire),  
    constraint Document_c CHECK ( Document is not null)) 

/

INSERT INTO exemplaire
          SELECT t_exemplaire( 1, 13, (SELECT REF(d) FROM document d WHERE d.IdDocument = 2) ) FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT t_exemplaire( 2, 42, (SELECT REF(d) FROM document d WHERE d.IdDocument = 1) ) FROM DUAL
/

create or replace type t_emprunt as object  
( IdEmprunt         Number(10),  
  DateD             DATE,    
  DateF             DATE,  
  Emprunteur_ref    ref t_emprunteur,  
  Exemplaire_ref    ref t_exemplaire )

/

create table emprunt of t_emprunt(  
    primary key(IdEmprunt),  
    Emprunteur_ref scope is emprunteur,  
    Exemplaire_ref scope is exemplaire,  
    DateD default sysdate)    
/

INSERT INTO emprunt
          SELECT t_emprunt( 1,
                            SYSDATE,
                            SYSDATE - 1,
                            (SELECT REF(e) FROM emprunteur e WHERE e.IdEmprunteur = 1),
                            (SELECT REF(e) FROM exemplaire e WHERE e.IdExemplaire = 2)
                          ) FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT t_emprunt( 2,
                            TO_DATE( '2000/01/01', 'YYYY/MM/DD' ),
                            TO_DATE( '2001/12/31', 'YYYY/MM/DD' ),
                            (SELECT REF(e) FROM emprunteur e WHERE e.IdEmprunteur = 2),
                            (SELECT REF(e) FROM exemplaire e WHERE e.IdExemplaire = 1)
                          ) FROM DUAL
/

CREATE INDEX emprunt_emprunteur_ref_idx ON emprunt (Emprunteur_ref)
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT e.IdEmprunt,
       e.Emprunteur_ref.IdEmprunteur,
       e.Exemplaire_ref.IdExemplaire,
       e.Exemplaire_ref.NumeroRayon,
       e.Exemplaire_ref.Document.IdDocument
FROM   emprunt e
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/213ef9/4/0)**:

```
| IDEMPRUNT | EMPRUNTEUR_REF.IDEMPRUNTEUR | EXEMPLAIRE_REF.IDEXEMPLAIRE | EXEMPLAIRE_REF.NUMERORAYON | EXEMPLAIRE_REF.DOCUMENT.IDDOCUMENT |
|-----------|-----------------------------|-----------------------------|----------------------------|------------------------------------|
|         1 |                           1 |                           2 |                         42 |                                  1 |
|         2 |                           2 |                           1 |                         13 |                                  2 |
```